# PHP DOM get items from first ul element

Tags: php, dom, element

I have html file which looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>smth 1 2 3..</li>
 <li>another</li>
<ul>
<ul>
 <li>smth 1 2 3..</li>
 <li>another</li>
<ul>
```

I am trying to get elements only from first ul list. I am using this code, but it returns errors:

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($data);
            $postalCodesList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
            foreach ($postalCodesList->item(0) as $postalCodesList) {
                 echo $postalCodesList->nodeValue.'<br />';

            }
?>
```

Comment: What errors does it return?

Comment: I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net to do this type of job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing a DomNode to foreach will not allow you to iterate through its childen, you can easily get the list of `li`s and iterate through them.

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($data);
    $postalCodesList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
    foreach ($postalCodesList->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('li') as $postalCodesList) {
        echo $postalCodesList->nodeValue.'<br />';                    
    }
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/49Uh3kjD)