# php DOMDocument - List child elements to array

Tags: php

For the following **HTML**:

```
<html>
<body>
<div whatever></div>
<div id="archive-wrapper">
<ul class="archive-list">
    <li><div><a href="#1">A</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#2">B</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#3">C</a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

How could I retrieve, **with PHP DOMDocument**  (http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php), an array containing `(#1,#2,#3)` in the most effective way? It's not that I did not try anything or that I want an already done code, I just need to know some guidelines to do it and understand it on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to do it by jQuery or php?

Comment: in that case you need to build the list with php while creating an array or post it to a form.

Comment: @unixmiah How would posting it to a form help? And what do you man by building the list while creating the array? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example using php DOMDocument -

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
<div whatever></div>
<div id="archive-wrapper">
<ul class="archive-list">
    <li><div><a href="#1">A</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#2">B</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#3">C</a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

//get all links
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$linkArray = array();

//loop through each link
foreach ($links as $link){
    $linkArray[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

**edit**
to get only the links inside `ul`->`li`, you could do something like -

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$linkArray = array();

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $li){
    foreach ($li->getElementsByTagName('li') as $a){
        foreach ($a->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
            $linkArray[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
}
```

or if you just want the 1st `ul` you could simplify to

```
//get 1st ul using ->item(0)
$ul = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);
foreach ($ul->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li){
    foreach ($li->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
        $linkArray[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a better example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me to understand it better. But, what if there are more links in the same HTML document? How can I specifically get only those INSIDE the Li Inside the Ul?

Comment: i would use getElementsByTagName and getAttribute. here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553572/php-dom-get-items-from-first-ul-element

Comment: I have added an edit that shows how you can loop through your `ul`/`li` to get the links.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time. I am learning a lot with your examples. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean with PHP DOM? do you mean with PHP and JQuery? You can setup

- you can put all that in a form and post it to a script
- you can also wrap around a select which will only store the selected
  data
- better idea would be to jquery to post the items to an array on the
  same page   and using php as a processor for server side
  munipilation? this is better in the long run, being its the most updated way of 
  interacting with html and server side scripts.

for example, you can try either way:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){ //form being the #form id
    var items = [];
    $("#archive-list li").each(function(n){
        items[n] = $(this).html();
    });

   $.post(
      "munipilate-data.php", 
      {items: items}, 
      function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer, but I need to do it in PHP to save the retrieved data in a database. There is a PHP class for this: http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a regex to parse it.

```
$html = '<html>
    <body>
       <div whatever></div>
       <div id="archive-wrapper">
       <ul class="archive-list">
            <li><div><a href="#1">A</a></div></li>
            <li><div><a href="#2">B</a></div></li>
            <li><div><a href="#3">C</a></div></li>
       </ul>
       </div>
    </body>';
$reg = '/a href=["\']?([^"\' ]*)["\' ]/';
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $m);
$arr = array_map(function($v){
    return trim(str_replace('a href=', '', $v), '"');
}, $m[0]);

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => #1
    [1] => #2
    [2] => #3
)
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dB7nG1/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I prefer using the PHPDocument class since it will be more complex than the example I posted. But thanks a lot, have a nice day :)