# How get list subItens nodes separateds using PHP DOM

Tags: php, list, dom

I was seeing this tip
[PHP DOM get items from first ul element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553572/php-dom-get-items-from-first-ul-element#)

But in this case:

```
<li>First item
   <ul>
     <li>
       First SubItem
     </li>
     <li>
       Second SubItem
     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

PHP Code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $DOM->loadHTML( $output);
        $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('ul');

            echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($items->item(3)->getElementsByTagName('li')        as $li) {
                    var_dump($li);die();
                    echo '<li>'.$li->nodeValue;
                        $ul = $li->getElementsByTagName('ul');
                            echo '<ul>';
                    echo '--->'.$ul->length.'<br>';
                        for($u=0;$u<$ul->length;$u++){
                            foreach ($ul->item($u)->getElementsByTagName('li') as $lii) {
                                echo '<li>'.$lii->nodeValue.'</li>';
                            }
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
```

The Problem is:
Im getting in //$li->nodeValue;// "First itemFirst SubItemSecond SubItem" as the Fist node;
I need get this items separated (subItems)

Comment: don't understand your problem

Comment: The Problem is: Im getting in //$li->nodeValue;// "First itemFirst SubItemSecond SubItem" as the Fist node; I need get this items separated (subItems)

Comment: Might want to look at `DOMXPath` it'll simplify things massively : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Im Loading HTML from a remote website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to retrieve the text values from those `<li>` tags.

You can greatly simplify the query with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) as `->query('//li')` will fetch **all** `<li>` tags in your code snippet.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($output);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
if($xpResponse = $xPath->query('//li/text()')) {
    echo "<ul>\n";

    foreach($xpResponse as $xNode) {
        echo "<li>" . trim($xNode->nodeValue) . "</li>\n";
    }

    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

This will simply output (as HTML):

- First item
- First SubItem
- Second SubItem

Comment: Pretty Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @hoheckell I know right ;) - XPath has probably stopped me from becoming a complete gibbering wreck when dealing with XML parsing.